# How to know previously selected language in the localization?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

I have two languages, English and Gujarati for UI. If, At the time of closing UI language is Gujarati, then at the opening time also language should be Gujarati. How do I know this: ?? the code for language selection is here.

```
ComboBoxItem englishLanguageItem = new ComboBoxItem()
        { 
            Content = Strings.MainWindow_Language_Selection_English_Label
        };

        ComboBoxItem gujaratiLanguageItem = new ComboBoxItem()
        {
            Content = Strings.MainWindow_Language_Selection_Gujarati_Label
        };
```

Please give some code regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem. You need to know what was the last selected language, so when your program is re-open, it comes up with that language?

If so, you have to save it somewhere, maybe on registry.

Here you can check how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

Comment: if last language is (Gujarati) ગુજરાતી then it need to be opened as Gujarati.

Comment: which type of registry  you have any idea about it?

Comment: I was talking about Windows Registry. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)

Comment: in registry what i have to store?How?

Comment: Check the link on my answer. It teachs you how to read from/write to registry.

Comment: can i save it using :Settings.Default["UILanguage"] = CultureManager.UICulture.Name;
            Settings.Default.Save();

Comment: Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Check for **Saving User Settings at Run Time**